# Remote app server deployment

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, war

I want to deploy WAR package when I build it with Netbeans on remote server.

One solution that I found is to use maven-cargo plugin. Have you tried this plugin with JBoss and WebLogic? But are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

**For Weblogic** 
Netbeans 8.1 allows you to add a remote Weblogic server.

Right click on Servers and select "Add Server" -> "Remote Domain"

[image]

**For JBoss, Tomcat etc.**

I secure copy my war to the remote server on the command line to the auto deploy or webapps directory.
It's quick and easy in my opinion.

(Maven cargo gave me grey hair...)